# How to select the rows with duplicate values in a table?

Tags: sqlite

How does one select a certain column whose got values of same value in another column? In this case, the aim is to select the names of the people who teach in the same class. So how does one select the names of the peple who teach in the same class?

```
kcode             kname                                               name
---------------  --------------------------------------------------  ----------
TIG098           eBusiness and eGovernment                           Agneta
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och informationssystem        Aida
TIG058           Programmeringsteknik och databaser                  Alan
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt                            Dina
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem                                   Faramarz
TIG166           Tillampad IT management                             Fredrik
TIG167           Fordjupning i programmering                         Henrik
TIG016           Verksamheter och information                        Janne
TIG067           Examensarbete                                       Johan
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och informationssystem        Jonas
TIG164           Interaktionsdesign                                  Juha
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och informationssystem        Kalle
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och informationssystem        Kjell
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och informationssystem        Lennart
TIG098           eBusiness and eGovernment                           Lisen
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och informationssystem        Magnus
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och informationssystem        Maria
TIG165           Informatik som vetenskap                            Marie
TIG167           Fordjupning i programmering                         Rikard
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och informationssystem        Urban
TIG165           Informatik som vetenskap                            William
```

The expected results should be that of:

```
Agneta
Aida
Henrik
Jonas
Kalle
Kjell
Lennart
Lisen
Magnus
Maria
Marie
Rikard
Urban
William
```

Comment: Please show us the results that you expect for this sample data.

Comment: Yes did so now sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `EXISTS`:

```
select t.name
from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where name <> t.name and kcode = t.kcode
)  
order by t.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ML4NsRh88RJZHQAoqundw/1).
Results:

```
| name    |
| ------- |
| Agneta  |
| Aida    |
| Henrik  |
| Jonas   |
| Kalle   |
| Kjell   |
| Lennart |
| Lisen   |
| Magnus  |
| Maria   |
| Marie   |
| Rikard  |
| Urban   |
| William |
```

Or with group_concat() for each class:

```
select kcode, kname, group_concat(name) names
from tablename
group by kcode, kname
having count(*) > 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ML4NsRh88RJZHQAoqundw/0).
Results:

```
| kcode  | kname                                        | names                                             |
| ------ | -------------------------------------------- | ------------------------------------------------- |
| TIG015 | Informationsteknologi och informationssystem | Aida,Jonas,Kalle,Kjell,Lennart,Magnus,Maria,Urban |
| TIG098 | eBusiness and eGovernment                    | Agneta,Lisen                                      |
| TIG165 | Informatik som vetenskap                     | Marie,William                                     |
| TIG167 | Fordjupning i programmering                  | Henrik,Rikard                                     |
```

Comment: Is there another way to do this besides doing concat since i havent learnt how to use that yet

Comment: Sorry for the concern, but that one seems to be even more complicated. can you post the concat one again and ill mark it as solved thank you man